# crash on compare Spinner selected item to String

Tags: android, spinner, equals

I am trying to compare a string to the selected item of my Spinner. But when I run my application stops and i get this error message:

java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.box.wassing.rocbox.fragment_afmelden$1.onClick(fragment_afmelden.java:90)

```
final Spinner sp_leslocatie = (Spinner) myFragmentViewAfmelden.findViewById(R.id.sp_leslocatie);


btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("TEST", "btnSend clicked");

            String school0 = "Selecteer een school";


            if(cbSave.isChecked() == true) {
                // saveData();
            } else {
                // clearData();
            }

            if(sp_leslocatie.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(school0)){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TEST.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
});
```

Comment: It is always useful to know which line the error occurs on...

Comment: I think `sp_leslocatie` is `null`, check it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add check that `getSelectedItem()` is not null, if you haven't select anything manually it is not set.